# Get GLSL vertex shader positions back to use on cpu event collider functions

Tags: kivy, glsl, shader, render, vertex

I'm using python kivy to render meshes with opengl onto a canvas. I want to return vertex data from the fragment shader so i can build a collider (to use on my cpu event listeners after doing projection and model view transforms). I can replicate the matrix multiplications on the cpu (i guess that's the easy way out), but then i would have to do the same calculations twice (not good).

The only way I can think of doing this (after some browsing) is to imprint an object id onto my rendered mesh alpha channel (wouldn't affect much if i'd keep data coding near value 1 for alpha ). And create some kind of 'color picker' on the cpu side to decode it (I'm guessing that's not hard to do using kivy).

Anyone has a better idea to deal with this? Or a better approach?

Comment: I don't think it's very efficient to inspect the pixel output of your shaders, although there may be ways to optimise it. Perhaps using some kind of compute shader might be efficient, but that's outside kivy's scope. I would be wary of premature optimisation - is it actually slow to do your collision check on the cpu? What about if you use an efficient collision library?

Comment: i guess it could work for now, i'm actually only rendering simple cubes to the canvas. but what if i'll start rendering complex shapes from obj-like files like i'm planning to do? how efficient should the collision library be? or how precise?

Comment: I'm no expert on collision, but I think in general it's simplest to do collision in terms of approximate polygons. This is extremely fast and efficient. Whether this is good enough for you is basically up to you and the task you're trying to achieve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First criterion here is: do you need collision **for picking** or **for physics** simulation?

If it is for physics: you almost never want the same mesh for rendering and for physics collisions. Typically, you use a very rough approximation for the physics shape, nearly always a convex shape, or a union of convex shapes. (Colliding arbitrary concave meshes is something that no physics engine can do well, and if they attempt it at all, performance will be poor.)

If it is for the purpose of picking an object with a mouse-click: you can go two different ways for this:

1. You **replicate the geometry** on the CPU, and use the mouse-location plus camera-view to create a ray that intersects this geometry, to see what is hit first.
2. After rendering your scene, you **read back** a single pixel from the depth buffer. (The pixel that your mouse is over.) With the depth value you get back, plus camera info, you can reconstruct a corresponding 3D position in your world. Once you have a 3D location, you can query your world to see which object is the closest to this point, and you will have your hit.